# Can't push/update data into existing mongo object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have a user object which consists of a couple of arrays inside it, which looks like this:

```
{
  _id: "5b90a261ff3712000495ca29", 
  name: "Udit", 
  email: "guru.udit@bmail.com", 
  password: "sjsndj",
  education:[],
  professionalexp:[],
  projects:[],
  skills:[]
}
```

I am using express API to push data into education array with some object, the following is the code I am trying to update mongo data. When I try to push and update data I see no response. How should I go about and push array or multiple arrays at once?

```js
app.put("/api/updatefield/", function(req, res) {
  User.update(
    { _id: req.body._id },
    {
      $push: {
        "education.$.University": "something that is there"
      }
    },
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      if (result) {
        res.json(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

also for reference, this is data I am pushing through API body, which I am getting in req.body on the rest server

```
{
    "summary": "some summary",
    "education": [
        {
            "name": "Institue",
            "from": "19/07/2018",
            "to": "30/07/2018"
        }
    ],
    "professional": [
        {
            "name": "Company",
            "from": "19/07/2018",
            "to": "30/07/2018"
        }
    ],
    "cardCount": 1,
    "cardCount2": 1
}
```

Comment: if your array is more then just array of text/strings you better have a look on the sub-document way of doing things.

Comment: I have objects inside array. What other way i can do this?

Comment: i prefer to define (in mongoose) the type i use in the array, so i can cast it correctly before the push.

Comment: I’ve defined it in the Schema

Comment: yes - what i am asking you to do is to make a separate definition of the type inside the array so you can cast to it before the push. (I had i situation with a nested array (array with a array inside) where i had to do this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
User.update({_id: ObjectId("5b910b0acb5b7646e630cefe")}, {
    $push: {
        "education": {
            "summary": "some summary",
            "education": [{"name": "Institue", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
            "professional": [{"name": "Company", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
            "cardCount": 1, "cardCount2": 1
        }
    }
})
```

For multiple objects:

```
User.update({_id: ObjectId("5b910b0acb5b7646e630cefe")}, {
    $push: {
        "education": {
            $each: [{
                "summary": "some summary",
                "education": [{"name": "Institue", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
                "professional": [{"name": "Company", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
                "cardCount": 1, "cardCount2": 1
            }, {"a": 2}]
        }    
    }
})
```

For pushing into more than 1 object:

```
User.update({_id: ObjectId("5b910b0acb5b7646e630cefe")}, {
        $push: {
            "education": {
                $each: [{
                    "summary": "some summary",
                    "education": [{"name": "Institue", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
                    "professional": [{"name": "Company", "from": "19/07/2018", "to": "30/07/2018"}],
                    "cardCount": 1, "cardCount2": 1
                }, {"a": 2}]
            },
           "professionalexp" : {"a":2}
        }
    })
```

Comment: Would it still work if i have more than one objects in array?

Comment: The data you are pushing is not an array, its an object but if you have to push multiple objects you have to run $each on array of objects

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this

Comment: Hey, just find my update.I have done it for multiple objects as well.

Comment: HI, I actually want to push multiple objects inside only education and professional

Comment: You can do that easily by adding one more object, just updated the answer for you.

Comment: `{n: 0, nModified: 0, opTime: {…}, electionId: "7fffffff0000000000000007", ok: 1, …}` this is all i am getting. also not updating the data

Comment: Bro, all the queries have been tested they are updating the docs successfully, you can try it on any IDE.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Can you tell me why we are using {“a”:2}

Comment: Yes, it's just a dummy one. You may insert whatever you want